# Why categorical_accuracy is low when training a MLP?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I am training a 3 layer MLP in keras. The dataset is heavily imbalanced and would like to increase the detectability rate of the model.

Whenever I encoded the target/independent variable as numerical (i.e. mapped from string to number) the categorical_category score was close to 0.37. Using a category_optimizer.

When I changed the target/independent variable to a categorical (i.e. one hot encoded), the score reported shot up to 0.90.

However, one of minority classes (and most important classes) as not being classified correctly or not at all.

I am delving into the recall score rather than precision.

Other techniques employed: class weights and upsampling minority classes.

I find it easier to work WITHOUT onehotencoded target variables.

5 classes in total (1 class represents the majority, 4 other classes represent abnormality and are in minority)

Comment: Give some info on your output data

Comment: Hi Konstantinos, thanks for replying. Here you may find a document with much more info. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SmGNeB5h0QZQp_PQ7WO-2zp_uktEf5G7

Answer (score 0):

You **need** to use one-hot encoding in all classification problems, as otherwise you are implying numerical structure and order on your classes which simply is not there (i.e. the *number* 2 is closer to 1 than to 4, but that will not be the case for *class* 2 to 1 and 4). You can still resample your data or use per-class weighting to improve recall against precision.

Comment: Thanks Konstantinos. Right will go for onehotencoding as it makes sense as it gives the target variable an order. One of the reasons of not doing so as I didn't yet find out how to generate a confusion matrix with such a configuration. What metrics would you adequate to use? Would f1score, recall and precision make sense.

Comment: You can convert your one-hot predictions to numeric class values by simply calling `np.argmax()` on the correct axis. You can easily use any metric; which one you choose depends on where you place the emphasis on, prediction-wise. Also if you find the answer acceptable, please make sure to mark it so.

Comment: Indeed, I had managed to use np.argmax() to convert the predictions accordingly.  My issue now is using scores to score my model with GridSearchCV.

Comment: Indeed thanks, I had managed to use np.argmax() to convert the predictions accordingly.  My issue now is using scores to score my model with GridSearchCV due to the class imbalance issue.  Error message reads: "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets". Weighted parameter is being specified. y is OneHotEncoded.

Comment: grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier,
                    param_grid=param_grid,
                    n_jobs=no_cpu_jobs,
                    scoring=f1_scorer,
                    cv=cv_splits)                                                                      
recall_scorer  = make_scorer(score_func=metrics.recall_score,greater_is_better=True,average='weighted')
f1_scorer      = make_scorer(score_func=f1_score,greater_is_better=True,average='weighted')